# Time-evolution under Bogoliubov-de-Gennes Hamiltonian

Tags: fermions, superconductivity, majorana-fermions

Consider a (Gaussian / quadratic / non-interacting) free-fermion Hamiltonian on $N$ modes which is not particle-number conserving, i.e., a Bogoliubov-de-Gennes / superconducting / Majorana Hamiltonian
$$\hat H = H_{ij} c_i c_j^\dagger + \frac12(\Delta_{ij} c_i c_j + 
\Delta^*_{ij} c_j^\dagger c_i^\dagger)\;.$$

How do I calculate the matrix entries
$$ \langle 0| c_i \hat U c_j^\dagger |0\rangle$$
and
$$ \langle0| \hat U c_i^\dagger c_j^\dagger |0\rangle$$
where $\hat U$ is the (imaginary or real) time evolution operator $\hat U = e^{\alpha \hat H}$ where $\alpha$ could be real or imaginary.

In the particle-number conserving case $\Delta=0$, we simply have $\langle 0| c_i \hat U c_j^\dagger |0\rangle = U_{ij}$ where $U = e^{\alpha H}$. What is the analogous formula for the superconducting case?